# LightGBM running simulation after each fit step

Tags: python, xgboost, lightgbm

My model performs a multi-class (3) classification task.

I would like to change the way model "fits". Instead of calculation of a metric such as `acc` or `logloss` - I would like to run a simulation on whole data set to see how the model performs **after each fit**, in real-time.

*Please note that **simulation** != **loss/error**. Simulation takes into the consideration time component of the data, the sequence in which events occur. Whereas the loss function simply calculates the error based on true values.*

Currently I do the simulation after the whole "fitting" process has been done:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
all_ds = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)
train_ds = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train)
test_ds = lgb.Dataset(X_test, label=y_test)

params = {
    'device_type': "gpu",
    'objective': 'multiclass',
    'metric': 'multi_logloss',
    "boosting_type": "gbdt",
    "num_class": 3,
    'random_state': 123
}

# fit
model = lgb.train(
    params,
    train_ds,
    num_boost_round=20
    valid_sets=[test_ds]
)

# make prediction on a whole data set
y_pred= model.predict(all_ds)

# simulate
simulation_result = simulate(X, y_pred) # float value
```

current process is:

1. fit step 1 - error x
2. fit step 2 - error y
3. ..
4. fit step 20 - error z
5. simulate - see how the model performs

I would like to change the process to

1. fit step 1 - simulate - use result of simulation as an error
2. fit step 2 - simulate - use result of simulation as an error
3. ..
4. fit step 20 - simulate - use result of simulation as an error

Is there a way to achieve it through a custom **callback** or a custom **evaluation metric** or some other way?

I tried creating a custom eval metric, unfortunately I cannot invoke `predict()` from within the function. Moreover I find the `preds` parameter value to be something I cannot simply use without transformations of some sort.. It contains some sort of multidimensional array that I have no idea how to convert to actual predictions.

```
def customEvalMetric(preds, eval_data):
    # how to invoke predict() method on a whole dataset here?
    # OR how to convert preds to one-hot encoded values?

    # simulation_result = simulate(all_ds, ..?..)

    return 'simulation_result', simulation_result, True
```

and using as

```
model = lgb.train(
    params,
    train_ds,
    num_boost_round=20
    valid_sets=[all_ds],
    feval=customEvalMetric,
)
```

p.s. now that I think about it - I could in theory fit once in a loop, then use `init_model` to load the existing model weights.. Is this the only way?

I suppose this question is applicable to other tree boosting libraries since the API are similar (`xgboost` for example)

Answer (score 0):

The custom eval function should work. As per the [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.train.html#lightgbm.train), `preds` is:

> The predicted values. Predicted values are returned before any transformation, e.g. they are raw margin instead of probability of positive class for binary task.

So if this is a classification problem, you might need to apply the softmax transformation to each row. For a regression problem, you should be able to use this output as-is.